# When running anonymous apex in VS Code can I filter the output to show only the system.debug?

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

When running anonymous apex in the Developer Console, you have the option to filter down to show only the Debug lines - is this possible when running anonymous apex from VS Code?

I see the full output in the Output panel and can manually scroll through to find the debug lines.

I can use SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs to retrieve the full debug log too - what's the best method to filter down to only the debug lines?

Should it be this command to launch the debugger? I'm missing this option.

> SFDX: Launch Apex Replay Debugger with Current File

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to see live logs

```
sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | grep USER_DEBUG
```

the grep USER_DEBUG will display only lines related to System.debug calls

You can also run this command with a single click using [VsCode SFDX Hardis extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) with command *Display live logs in terminal*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had just installed the Hardis extension and was looking through it too. When I run the anon apex vs code automatically open the Output tab - is there a way to stop it so it remains on the terminal where the debug log shows?

Comment: Run anonymous code command is managed in Salesforce core Vs Code extensions, so Sfdx Hardis has no way to change that :/

Comment: if it can help, code is here, you may ask the maintainers for a PR that would allow some connfig param to not switch of output tab when running the command :)
https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/blob/main/packages/salesforcedx-vscode-apex/src/commands/forceAnonApexExecute.ts